# trouble in deleting root node in tree

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct Node{

    int data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

Node* new_node(int data1)
{

    Node* new_node=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    new_node->data=data1;
    new_node->left=NULL;
    new_node->right=NULL;
    return new_node;

}

void Display(Node* root)
{
    if(root!=NULL)
    {//printf("\nhi123\n");
        Display(root->left);
        printf("%d ",root->data);
        Display(root->right);

    }

}


void convertTreeToDll(Node* root,Node** head)
{

    if(root==NULL)
     return ;

     if(root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL)
     {

        if(*head==NULL)
        {

            *head=new_node(root->data);

        printf("\nhi1234\n");           
        }else
        {
            Node* head1=*head;
               printf("\nhello head1->data=%d\n",head1->data)    ;



            Node* temp=new_node(root->data);
            cout<<"temp adress="<<temp<<"   root address="<<root<<"  head1="<<head1<<endl;
            head1->left=temp;
            temp->right=head1;

            head1=temp;
            cout<<"temp adress="<<temp<<"   root address="<<root<<"  head1="<<head1<<endl;
        }

     }
    convertTreeToDll(root->left,head);
    convertTreeToDll(root->right,head);

}


void DoubleLinkList(Node* root)
{
    if(root!=NULL)
    {

        printf("%d ",root->data);
        root=root->right;
    }


}

void convertUtil(Node* root)
{



     printf("\ndata=%d\n",root);
     Node* head=NULL;

     convertTreeToDll(root,&head);
     //while(head->left!=NULL)
     //head=head->left;
    DoubleLinkList(head);
}

void change(Node** root1)
{

    Node* root=*root1;
    cout<<" root="<<root<<"  *root1="<<*root1<<endl;
    if(root==NULL)
     return;
     //printf("\nhi\n");
     change(&(root->left));
     change(&(root->right));
     free(root);
     root=NULL;
}
int main()
{
    Node* root=new_node(1);
    root->left=new_node(2);
    root->right=new_node(3);
    Display(root);
    change(&root);
    //cout<<endl<<"root->left="<<root->left->data<<endl;
    //root->left=new_node(20);
    Display(root);
    Node* head=NULL;
  // convertTreeToDll(root,&head);
   //printf("\nhead->data=%d\n",head);
   //convertUtil(root);

    return 0;
}
```

In change function when i set `*root1 =NULL` it is working properly.But when i set `root=NUL`L it is not coming NULL when program control moves to display function.Please help out.

when i set `root=NULL` the output is :

```
2 1 3
0 34979904 34979872
```

Comment: `root` is an automatic, non-reference variable.  assigning its value is meaningless to the caller.

Comment: You want to zero `*root` instead of `root` inside `change()`. Also, get a good C++ tutorial, it shows in many places that you need one.

Comment: I was going to suggest whatever "Move to C++ from C At Your Own Pace" you were using would better serve its life heating your home. *None* of them are decent, and *most* of them are beyond terrible.

Comment: @WhozCraig my question is that if I going to print memory address of root and *root1 are same...if set *root1=NULL it works fine. my question is that both *root1 and root point to same memory location if I set root=NULL then it gives unexpected result.

Comment: @user2365107 And thus my first comment. You seem to think that somehow `Node* root=*root1;` means latter changing `root` by assignment will change `*root1`, the pointer addressed by the pointer-to-pointer passed as your parameter; it *won't*. No more than `int a=5, b=a; b=4;` will change the value of `a` to 4. This is fundamental, and it is somewhat critical you understand it or C++ references are really going to toss you for a loop.